# Perform MID or LEFT on ARRAY

Tags: excel, excel-formula

MATCH requires an array as the second parameter.

eg. `=MATCH(Sheet1!A1 ; Sheet2!A1:A4 ; 0)`

Is there a way to match the substrings of the array values in the lookup using LEFT/MID?

eg. `=MATCH(Sheet1!A1 ; LEFT(Sheet2!A1:A4;5) ; 0)`

The above example gives a #VALUE! error, I understand why it is not working, I just want to know if there is a way to acheive the desired result? MATCHING using only a substring from each value in the array?

Comment: you can use wildcard for the same effect: `=MATCH(Sheet1!A1 & "*" ; Sheet2!A1:A4 ; 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can array enter the formula to make it work. By that, I mean that you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing in the formula instead of simply hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.